# SQL Group by different time periods with day

Tags: sql

I need to query a sales table and have the resulting table show the breakdown for different time periods within the given day.

For example, the table has the following fields:

```
Id (int), EntryDate (datetime), SaleReference (varchar)
```

I'd like to produce a table that looks like this:

```
Date        Sales 9am-12pm   Sales 12pm-3pm   Sales 6pm-9pm
----------  --------------   --------------   -------------
01-01-2010        10               20               6  
02-01-2010        12               16               3  
03-01-2010        43               11               2
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Stephen - What RDBMS and version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server below. If not a similar logic will probably apply with your RDBMS but likely a different function to get the hour part from the datetime and the behaviour of BETWEEN may be different too (In SQL Server it is an inclusive range).

```
SELECT CAST([Date] AS Date) AS [Date],
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [Date]) BETWEEN 9 AND 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    AS [Sales 9am-12pm],
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [Date]) BETWEEN 12 AND 14 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    AS [Sales 12pm-3pm],
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [Date]) BETWEEN 18 AND 20 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    AS [Sales 6pm-9pm]
FROM Table
GROUP BY CAST([Date] AS Date) /*For SQL2008*/
```

NB: Previous versions of SQL Server require a few more hoops to get just the date part out of a datetime. e.g. `CAST(FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME` (From [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/122-Getting-Only-the-Date-Part-of-a-Date-Time-Stamp-in-SQL-Server.htm))

Comment: You're grouping by the date, which is going to be a datetime. It's not going to group correctly, unfortunately. Cast the Date as a Date, and in the select put the same cast and it'll be fixed up. +1 now :)

Comment: @Mike - Good spot. Fixed now.

Comment: That is just perfect. Thank you to Martin and Mike. :-)

Comment: Sorry... coming back to this again ;-)

If the table contained a column containing the sale value, how would i get the total sale value for each time period?

Comment: Add `SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, [Date]) BETWEEN 9 AND 11 THEN salesVal ELSE 0 END) AS [Sales Value 9am-12pm]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database supports this kind of date math, you can say:

```
CASE WHEN EntryDate - date(EntryDate) >= INTERVAL '9 hours'
      AND EntryDate - date(EntryDate) < INTERVAL '12 hours'
     THEN ...
```

(That's the PostgreSQL interval syntax, btw... might be nonstandard.)  But there are probably more elegant ways of doing it.